# How to find out the optimal number of forked kids

Tags: php, linux, memory, fork

I have a comprehensive PHP script (on Linux) which occasionally needs to do a lot of network talking. For that it forks a number of kids. The question is how the script can identify the optimal number of them? If the number is too large, the server runs out of physical memory and kids start swapping - performance penalty. So how can I get the real amount of available physical memory? A 'free' command doesn't tell me the real picture for obvious reasons.

Comment: Why wouldn't `free` tell you this? Just take the line adjusted for buffers/cache...  AFAIK, there are no special rights needed to see the actual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`free` will give you a correct picture on the second row (not counting the row with headers). Here's an example output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2060420    1754008     306412          0      97264    1013548
-/+ buffers/cache:     643196    1417224
Swap:      1951888          0    1951888
```

The free column in the first row is pretty useless because the disk cache is in there as well. You seldom want any free memory at all on the first row.
On the second row, on the other hand, the disk cache is subtracted. That's the real current memory usage of the machine!

Here is a PHP function to read and parse the output of `GNU free`:

```
// Get system mem usage in kilobytes
// Returns: array($used, $free), or false on failure
function memory_usage() {
  exec('free -k', $lines, $error);
  if ($error) return false;
  $cols = preg_split('/\s+/', $lines[2]);
  return array((int) $cols[2], (int) $cols[3]);
}

// Usage:
list($used, $free) = memory_usage();
printf("used: %d\nfree: %d\n", $used, $free);
```